# Delete number attribute from sylius order table

Tags: php, sylius

I am trying to delete the number attribute from the Sylius order table. Since the number attribute is in the vendor folder I could not delete it, so in the child order entity constructor, I did unset the number, but it is not working.
Please let me know how to delete it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason why you would want to remove such an essential part of an e-commerce platform. How will you track an order without a number?

Comment: To generate numbers, we are using sylius number generator which is generating duplicate, due to this orders are getting failed. And we are not using this number anywhere in our application,  So we are looking to delete this column. To track  an order, we have a separate property